# How to have a list take user input in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thetR.png)

I have tried different ways but still have not come up with a solution.

Comment: Please specifically give your code for easy replication and specify the error exactly so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner to python. I tried this and I dont know if this is what you are looking for or if there are better ways.

````
test = [1,2,3]
userinput = input(str("insert here:"))
test.append(userinput)
print(test)```
````